# Using ffmpeg to convert mxf to yuv

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, yuv

I am trying to convert mxf file to yuv using ffmpeg.
I gave the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i eldorado_really_cutdown.mxf output.yuv
```

But I am getting some errors. This is the output I am getting:

```
ffmpeg version N-63366-gf932e5f Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 21 2014 22:09:16 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gn
utls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enabl
e-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enabl
e-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid
--enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 86.100 / 52. 86.100
  libavcodec     55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100
  libavformat    55. 40.100 / 55. 40.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b20680] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b20680] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xEF5D7
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b20680] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1B0D30
Input #0, mxf, from 'eldorado_really_cutdown.mxf':
  Metadata:
    application_platform: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 (Build 7601)
    uid             : 7ad33f30-61ac-11e2-810f-0060dd46989e
    generation_uid  : 7ad33f30-61ac-11e2-8110-0060dd46989e
    company_name    : xxxxxxx
    product_name    : xxxxxxx
    product_uid     : xxxxxxx
    product_version : xxxxxxx
    modification_date: xxxxxxx
    timecode        : xxxxxx
  Duration: 00:00:08.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 458299 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: jpeg2000, yuv422p10le, 3840x2160, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
File 'output.yuv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'output.yuv':
  Metadata:
    application_platform: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 (Build 7601)
    uid             : 7ad33f30-61ac-11e2-810f-0060dd46989e
    generation_uid  : 7ad33f30-61ac-11e2-8110-0060dd46989e
    company_name    : xxxxxxx
    product_name    : xxxxxxx
    product_uid     : xxxxxxx
    product_version : xxxxxxx
    modification_date: xxxxxxx
    timecode        : xxxxxxxx
    encoder         : Lavf55.40.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y3[10][10] / 0xA0A3359), yuv422p10le, 3840x2160, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.63.100 rawvideo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (jpeg2000 -> rawvideo)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[jpeg2000 @ 000000000b4990e0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 000000000b4990e0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xEF5D7
[jpeg2000 @ 000000000b4990e0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1B0D30
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29080] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29080] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xEF70A
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b299a0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b299a0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xED534
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29520] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29520] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xEB823
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29520] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1AAA73
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29e40] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29e40] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xF1CBB
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29e40] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1B36F1
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29080] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1AF5CF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b299a0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1AE798
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Error number -12 occurred
[jpeg2000 @ 000000000b4990e0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 000000000b4990e0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xF43E1
[jpeg2000 @ 000000000b4990e0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1B7A09
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Error number -12 occurred
    Last message repeated 1 times
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29080] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29520] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29520] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xF2DD3
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29520] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1B31B1
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29080] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xF4A5F
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b29080] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1B7376
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Error number -12 occurred
    Last message repeated 1 times
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b299a0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xFF
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b299a0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0xF164D
[jpeg2000 @ 0000000002b299a0] unsupported marker 0xFF58 at pos 0x1B2C39
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

I am very new to video processing. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command did the trick
`ffmpeg.exe -codec:v libopenjpeg -i eldorado_really_cutdown.mxf output.yuv`